# Power-off button Linux module or package

Tags: linux, electrical-power

Is there any specific module/package in Linux responsible for initiating shut-down, once the power-off button was pressed?

I installed a minimal version of CentOS Linux by removing the base package, and the power-off button stopped working.

It does works fine in regular installation, so there must be some package missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yea, it's probably [ACPI support](http://www.linux.org/docs/ldp/howto/ACPI-HOWTO/index.html).

Chances are support is already compiled into your kernel. Look for /proc/acpi or /proc/sys/acpi. If you see them, skip to the "install ACPID" bit.

Assuming you DON'T have a kernel that supports acpi, [here's a little ACPI "How-To" for Fedora 8](http://www.mjmwired.net/resources/redhat8-acpi.html), which is admittedly not the same, but the process should be very similar. Here's [another](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_make_ACPI_work), more modern one.

If your kernel already supports acpi, you might want to simply try using a package manager to install [acpid](http://sourceforge.net/projects/acpid/) which should fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You may need the acpid-1.0.4-9.el5 package installed.